# Determining if Login is mapped to a specific database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am new to SQL Server 2008, so if this does not make sense at first, I will try to edit with clarification.

**Problem:**
I am trying to write a query that retrieves a list of all Logins that are currently mapped to a specified database.

**What I have tried:**
I am writing an application that lists all master Logins, what permissions they have, and if they are mapped to my specified database.  I have listed their permissions by using the `sys.server_permissions` table.  I have found that `sys.server_principals` shows the Login's default database name.  However, it does not show what databases the Login is mapped to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database users can be found in `sys.database_principals`. This will show you the database users and the logins they're mapped to.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.server_principals sp
INNER JOIN [your database].sys.database_principals dp
    ON sp.sid = dp.sid
```

Database permissions are stored in `sys.database_permissions`. A role is also a principle. You can find which roles a user belongs to in `sys.database_role_members`.

```
USE [your database];    
SELECT *
FROM sys.database_principals usr
INNER JOIN sys.database_role_members usr_roles
    ON usr.principal_id = usr_roles.member_principal_id
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals roles 
    ON usr_roles.role_principal_id = roles.principal_id
```

The tables/views that start with `database_` return data from the current database context.

Edit: fixed spelling of "principals"

Comment: Thank you. The first block of code works perfectly to show each Login that is mapped to my database.  I used a full outer join with `sys.database_principals` in my master Login producing query.

Answer (score 1):

You need a bunch of tables to do this - start with this:

```
SELECT [UserName] = ulogin.[name],
[UserType] = CASE princ.[type]
WHEN 'S' THEN 'SQL User'
WHEN 'U' THEN 'Windows User'
WHEN 'G' THEN 'Windows Group'
END,
[DatabaseUserName] = princ.[name],
[Role] = NULL,
[PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],
[PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],
[ObjectType] = CASE perm.[class]
WHEN 1 THEN obj.type_desc -- Schema-contained objects
ELSE perm.[class_desc] -- Higher-level objects
END,
[ObjectName] = CASE perm.[class]
WHEN 1 THEN OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id) -- General objects
WHEN 3 THEN schem.[name] -- Schemas
WHEN 4 THEN imp.[name] -- Impersonations
END,
[ColumnName] = col.[name]
FROM --database user
sys.database_principals princ
LEFT JOIN --Login accounts
sys.server_principals ulogin
ON princ.[sid] = ulogin.[sid]
LEFT JOIN --Permissions
sys.database_permissions perm
ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = princ.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN --Table columns
sys.columns col
ON col.[object_id] = perm.major_id
AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
LEFT JOIN sys.objects obj
ON perm.[major_id] = obj.[object_id]
LEFT JOIN sys.schemas schem
ON schem.[schema_id] = perm.[major_id]
LEFT JOIN sys.database_principals imp
ON imp.[principal_id] = perm.[major_id]
WHERE princ.[type] IN ('S', 'U', 'G')
AND -- No need for these system accounts
princ.[name] NOT IN ('sys', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA')
ORDER BY
ulogin.[name],
[UserType],
[DatabaseUserName],
[Role],
[PermissionState],
[PermissionType],
[ObjectType],
[ObjectName],
[ColumnName]
```

taken from http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic886424-359-1.aspx